# Doctrine OneToMany Relation with two joins

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I have the following table schema:

A table where persons are stored

```
CREATE TABLE `cdb_person` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `vorname` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
);
```

A table where groups are stored

```
CREATE TABLE `cdb_gruppe` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bezeichnung` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
```

A table where the membership of a person in a group ins stored

```
CREATE TABLE `cdb_person_gruppe` (
  `person_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `gruppe_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `group_member_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'active',
  `comment` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`person_id`,`gruppe_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `cdb_person_gruppe_gruppe_id_cdb_gruppe_id` FOREIGN KEY (`gruppe_id`) REFERENCES `cdb_gruppe` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `cdb_person_gruppe_person_id_cdb_person_id` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `cdb_person` (`id`)
)
```

For group memberships there can be fields defined per group.

```
CREATE TABLE `cdb_person_gruppe_field` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gruppe_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fieldname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `note` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sortkey` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `cdb_person_gruppe_field_gruppe_id_cdb_gruppe_id` FOREIGN KEY (`gruppe_id`) REFERENCES `cdb_gruppe` (`id`)
)
```

The value of the defined fields for the memberships can be saved in this table

```
CREATE TABLE `cdb_person_gruppe_fielddata` (
  `person_gruppe_field_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `person_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(512) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gemeindeperson_gruppe_field_id`,`person_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `cdb_person_gruppe_fielddata_person_gruppe_field_id_cdb_person_gruppe_field_id` FOREIGN KEY (`person_gruppe_field_id`) REFERENCES `cdb_person_gruppe_field` (`id`),
`cdb_person_gruppe_fielddata_person_id_cdb_person_id` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `cdb_person` (`id`)

);
```

I have a Entity `GroupMember` for the table `cdb_person_gruppe`.
There i want to add a relationship to the table `cdb_person_gruppe_fielddata` so that i have all the field data for the person in this group. But i need two joins to get only the necessary fields because the table `cdb_person_gruppe_field` holds the info for which group the field is defined.

So how can i make this OneToMany relationship?

To get all field values for a member in plain sql i would write this query:

```
select * from cdb_person_gruppe
JOIN cdb_person_gruppe_field ON cdb_person_gruppe.gruppe_id = cdb_person_gruppe_field.gruppe_id
JOIN cdb_person_gruppe_fielddata ON cdb_person_gruppe_fielddata.person_id = cdb_person_gruppe.person_id
WHERE cdb_person_gruppe.gruppe_id = 12 AND cdb_person_gruppe.person_id = 5;
```